# updating fields within a row across multiple tables in mySQL using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update, printf, implode

I've made an UPDATE statement below that incorporates the **sprintf()** and **implode([string glue], array pieces)** functions. These work fine for the entirety of the UDPDATE statement, until I need to

> SET table.column = field

I am using a multidimensional array to deposit user input values in **table**, **column**, and **field**, and cannot determine a method for formatting these arrays within an **implode()** statement so as to not violate its parameters.

The **implode()** function cannot take an array as its **[string glue]**, and **array pieces** cannot accept a string in its argument, but because the statement

> SET table.column = field

contains an array value between every possible **[string glue]** values of **.** and **=**, I cannot utilize **implode()** functions without compromising the UPDATE statement syntax structure with duplicate **.** or **=** operators or incorrectly formatted table, column, and field values.

example:

```
$query = sprintf(
   "UPDATE %s 
    SET %s %s %s
    WHERE %s C.id = '$id';",
        implode(", ", array_keys($updateFields)),  
        implode(" ", array_keys ($updateFields)),
        implode("." + array_keys($columns)),
        implode(" = " $columns),
        implode(".id = C_id AND ", array_keys($updateFields)),
)
```

results in

```
UPDATE A, B, C
    SET A B C 1.2.3.4.5.6.7.8.9.10.11.12.13 a = b = c = d = e = f = g = h = i = j = k = l = m            
    WHERE A.id = C_id AND B.id = C.id AND C._id = ' '
```

............

How should I be thinking about solving this problem?

I'd be happy to provide more information if anybody is interested.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no good solution :(

What you could do is build an array with the set statements in there and implode that.

Comment: Like having "table.column = field" as a value within the array?

Comment: Yeah or %s, but that could make it harder to debug when something is going wrong.